# Arabic support for Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, languages

Can you support the Arabic language for Stack Overflow, similarly to how other languages are now supported? It would be Stack Overflow, but all questions and answers would be in Arabic.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82176/258356

Comment: You're probably looking for the [Stack Exchange Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com). This meta site is about [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), which is English-only.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's not about SO, but about other sites in the SE network.

Comment: i want a site like stackoverflow not stack exchange but in arabic @Cerbrus

Comment: Then see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89647/stackoverflow-in-arabic

Comment: it seems like this topic was deleted on area51 du to not enough support/activity that would show i was worthing it.

Comment: There was a proposal for [Persian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97868) (same alphabet/writing direction, completely different language) that was declined recently. Arabic is notoriously painful to develop interfaces for because of a number of reasons (RTL, cursive, fewer polyglots).

Answer (score 43):

We're not planning support for additional languages in the immediate future. That's not to say that we're done, but it's going to be a while. There are a few major reasons for this:

#### We still need to hire a community manager per language.

There are many technical and philosophical reasons for this. Translation tools on the back end have improved from when we started, but they're still quite rough around the edges, and require oversight by someone with a considerable level of access to back-end things. We hope to *eventually* fix this to make localization easier going forward. However, if there's one thing we've learned about building new communities, it's that they need pretty skilled guidance. I don't think there's any way we can eliminate the human dependency here.

These are *extremely* difficult hires to make.

#### We have a lot of new products that have to bake.

Documentation, jobs, the developer story, teams and other initiatives we're cooking up for core Q&A need time to season properly, and then be deployed to the international sites, and then we'll have to do a lot of polishing.

We don't want to compound this any more, especially if it involves right-to-left languages. More on that later.

#### We're still learning what it means to be 'international'.

It goes *way* beyond translating a bunch of strings and opening the doors. Setting goals for sites in unfamiliar markets is *super hard*, and the challenges involved are unique to every site. We've got almost 20% of community growth's resources *dedicated* to internationalization and it's still a steep climb. It's totally worth it, in every sense of the word - but we're not in a position to scale that effort yet - we just have so much more to learn.

#### Right-to-left languages might never be possible.

We've looked into it, and from an engineering perspective, it would be *super* difficult to natively and properly support right-to-left languages. Yes, we can bolt some stuff on with a bunch of creative workarounds, but we're reluctant to put Stack Overflow on something *that* clobbered together. The aforementioned translation platform already resembles a [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine), I'm very reluctant to consider another language until we fix that, and that's already a huge undertaking. Supporting right-to-left text *properly* in conjunction with that is just gigantic.

I *hate* it when I have to say no, but I think we owe it to folks to honestly set their expectations. Yes, there are proposals on Area 51 for other languages that have been there for quite a while, and we've been pretty honest that we don't know when or if we'll be able to do them. But when we're *sure* that the answer is going to be no - it's better to just be honest about it.